# Counting Records in a json file?

Tags: php, json, facebook

I would like to know how to count records within records in json.

if you look here you can see an example of the text i have.

http://russellhopedesign.com/facebook/toplikedstatus/data.js

now. i want to see which record has the most "likes"

Would i have to do some sort of For Each and then count?

Comment: I'm sure the data on the other end of that link is nice, but can you post a small sample here?

Comment: It wont let me paste. i click add comment and it just does nothing

Comment: You can edit your question by clicking the "edit" link just below the "php, json, facebook" tags. Insert your JSON code, highlight it, and click the "{}" button to mark it as code.

Answer (score 0):

edit: Re-editied per ongoing conversation with the OP.

I would do a loop to start with, to loop over all the data.  have a variable to store the one you want to save, too.  then for each index, do a foor each loop, checking for the property and seeing if it's equal to "likes". Each time you find one that has a likes property, get the length and save it

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/100002367437090/statuses?limit=100000000&access_token=145634995501895|c19bad6810f80442a09516c5.0-100002367437090|wcIUgp977G3_nSiJTCF3mY_PMis'), true);        
    $data = $json['data'];
    $mostLiked = null;
    $saved = false;

    for($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++){
      foreach($data[$i] as $key => $value){
        //echo "property is => " . $key . '<br>';
        if($key == "likes"){
          //echo "********* a like is here";
          //echo '<br><hr>';
          //echo 'No. of likes => ' . count($data[$i]['likes']['data']) . '<br>';
          if(!$saved){
            //echo "*** nothing saved yet, save what we've just found <br>";
            $mostLiked = $data[$i];
            $saved = true;
          }else if($saved && (count($data[$i]['likes']['data']) > count($mostLiked['likes']['data']))){
            //echo "*** this one is bigger than what was saved before <br>";
            $mostLiked = $data[$i];
          };
        };
      };
    };
    //var_dump($mostLiked);
    echo 'This post has the most likes with => ' . count($mostLiked['likes']['data']);
```

Comment: I get the error : Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in

on the line   foreach($data[i] as $key => $value){

Comment: nm... i just ran a test and I see it coming back as JSON... one sec while i debug!

Comment: yeah. is that ok or should i change it?

Comment: ok i am pulling the json from facebook api now. like this

$graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/100002367437090/statuses?limit=100000000&access_token=145634995501895|c19bad6810f80442a09516c5.0-100002367437090|wcIUgp977G3_nSiJTCF3mY_PMis";
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url));

Comment: yeah, i've got it curl'd into my test page...just tweaking as I go.. haha.  almost there!  :D

Comment: I keep having problems.  I wonder if it's because the file isn't valid JSON(?).  I think all the property values needed to be quoted...

Comment: do you have skype? i will show your my source and how i call it from facebooks api

Comment: yes, but I am at work.  you should just post whatever you have in your post.  here's a way to make sure something is valis JSON.  http://jsonlint.com/  what you linked is just regular JS.  JSON needs to have everything properly quoted.

Comment: says it is valid. im doing file get contents from here. https://graph.facebook.com/100002367437090/statuses?limit=100000000&access_token=145634995501895|c19bad6810f80442a09516c5.0-100002367437090|wcIUgp977G3_nSiJTCF3mY_PMis and then decoding it.

Comment: oh... i was using the link from your OP... I got it now, haha.

Comment: yeah i thought i had better say, i mentioned it in a comment. does that make it easier?

Comment: im just getting decoded json :( http://russellhopedesign.com/facebook/toplikedstatus/

Comment: i was wanting it to display a number. and the one its displaying isn't the one with the most likes. its just showing the first one. i looked down the json and the most likes is 5

Comment: Thank you so much! "thescientist" for President!

Comment: excellent.  please accept my answer if it helped you.  Hopefully I can help you with more in the future.  :)